# About infinite loop and memory crash

Tags: c, memory, crash, infinite-loop

When I made a program using Visual Studio, I accidentally caught an infinite loop several times. I was embarrassed to see the same sentence being printed very quickly, so I just closed the console. However, when I searched it, it is said that if I get an infinite loop, I need to shut down the processor with ctrl + c.

What I'm worried about is the memory crash. In the microprocessor class, I learned that if I don't exit the infinite loop program properly, it will crash in memory. Is it true that the infinite loop keeps running even if I close the console? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Once you terminate the program, the infinite loop just stops there. If it keeps running for sometime, it will eventually crash

Comment: nothing will happen to your laptop. It's going to be fine. Just chill :)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I think it's a silly question... I'm embarrassed and want to delete it, what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Once you terminate the program, the infinite loop just stops there. If it keeps running for sometime, it will eventually crash.

Even if your loop is infinite, it will keep running and once it runs out of memory, it will crash and automatically get terminated. You could just as easily terminate a loop using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

#### Your PC will most probably be Fine

If you are worried if something would happen to your computer/laptop, in most cases  the answer would be **NO** . Your program will keep running for sometime( time will depend on what the type of loop you are running and process happening inside the loop) and afterwards, you will probably see slowdown of your computer and unresponsiveness. After consuming several GBs of your memory, the process will eventually **run out of memory space and would crash and terminate**. Once the process terminates, the system will claim back all the memory hogged by the process and everything will be back to normal as it was originally.

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the console application then your infinite loop also gets's terminated because the infinite loop is the part of your console window. If you're worried that your infinite loop doesn't terminate then you can simply check in the task manager (if there are any unnecessary process running in background or not).

**But it is not possible that(your infinite loop will be running ) after terminating the console window **

It does not harm your memory.